# Azure VM FTP Server Error: 550 Create directory operation failed

Tags: azure, ftp-server, azure-vm, azure-linux

I am trying to set home directory for FTP Server created on Azure VM (Linux) and I tried many ways taking help of google, but it throws error saying

1. If I add $USER in local_root while modifying /etc/vsftpd.conf file

**ftp> mkdir blob
550 Create directory operation failed.**

2. If I dont use $USER

**500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/ftp**

3. I have set below configuration  in **/etc/vsftpd.conf** file

```
    listen=NO
    
    listen_ipv6=YES
    
    anonymous_enable=NO
    
    local_enable=YES
    
    write_enable=YES
    
    anon_upload_enable=YES
    
    anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
    
    dirmessage_enable=YES
    
    use_localtime=YES
    
    xferlog_enable=YES
    
    connect_from_port_20=YES
    
    chroot_local_user=YES
    
    user_sub_token=$USER
    
    local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
    
    allow_writeable_chroot=YES
    
    pasv_enable=YES
    
    pasv_min_port=10000
    
    pasv_max_port=10010
    
    chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
    
    secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
    
    pam_service_name=vsftpd
    
    rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    
    rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
    
    ssl_enable=NO
```

Kindly help in fixing this issue while setting home directory for FTP Server (Azure VM).

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. We have two ways to short out this issue.

1. **ftpClient.DataConnectionType = FtpDataConnectionType.AutoActive**; Though this works out well, but this is not recommended.
2. **ftpClient.DataConnectionType = FtpDataConnectionType.AutoPassive**; This is recommended in case of Azure VM.
   And **to work it out**, we need to enable pasv_enable=true in AZURE VM through cmd and also have to enable port range in Azure VM through Portal.

```html
pasv_enable=Yes <br>
pasv_max_port=10010<br>
pasv_min_port=10000
```

Here is what I found as an explanation on Microsoft link-

> A multiregion deployment can use an active-active or active-passive configuration. An active-active configuration distributes requests across multiple active regions. An active-passive configuration keeps warm instances in the secondary region, but doesn't send traffic there unless the primary region fails.
> For more explanation please refer the link [Azure VM Active Passive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reliability/architect#:%7E:text=A%20multiregion%20deployment%20can%20use,unless%20the%20primary%20region%20fails.)

as it makes azure configuration mode which results all the traffic in open mode

Please suggest better approach if any.